# How to set encoding is in UTF-8 of jtextArea input?

Tags: java, multilingual

In my case,I have to pass different language as input in my jtextarea.
but when i print that text the string is not displayed properly.

```
data = txtdata.getText();
                String inputData = new String(data.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                System.out.println("entered data is :: "+data+" after formate cahnged :: "+inputData);
```

I have passed the input as:::
**నా పేరు అమిత్ ఉంది**

but i am not getting this text.
it prints **?? ???? ?? ?????**

please let me know the solution,what i have to deal with this.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Comment: Are you running this in a Windows command window?  I don't think a command window can display more than one code page of characters (256 characters).